# Load a dll library from GAC in a custom library

Tags: c#, dll

I have this scenario. I have an enterprise application which contains a class library which will be available in a computer if and only if this software is installed.

We are developing another class library using this library as a reference. The new class which we are developing provides a set of methods to perform some calculations and parse data, which will be useful any program which uses our newly developed class library.

The class library of the enterprise application present in the GAC has the same name, signature token but the version may be different.

How do I force my class library to use the enterprise application class library present in the GAC or any other path by the assembly name or the dll name, irrespective of the version of the dll present?

Comment: You have two libraries with the same name and token and one depends on another, correct?

Comment: You are asking for DLL Hell as a feature.  The GAC was designed to stop you from shooting your leg off like that.  You must use a .config file with the bindingRedirect element to pull the trigger anyway.

Comment: @Aik - yes, for example mscorlib.dll - in .net 1.0 and 3.5 this dll exists, but there may be enhancements in it. When my application is installed in two different machines which refers to two different versions of mscorlib.dll, both should work without recompiling. Is this possible?